# How to I wrap a UIKit view in SwiftUI with a delegate callback requiring a return value?

Tags: swiftui, uikit, arkit, uiviewrepresentable, swift-concurrency

The concrete usecase is that I want to wrap a `ARSCNView` in `UIViewRepresentable`.

The thing is, I want to expose the `ARSCNView`'s following properties:
`.delegate`
`.session.delegate`
`.session.delegateQueue`

and consider that some of the `ARSCNViewDelegate` method signatures have return values:

`func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?`

and I'm using this view in a pattern that has a

`@StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel // where ViewModel runs on @MainActor`

Now, I do have an approach that sort of works, but it doesn't handle the concurrency well, since any message sent to the viewModel would occur on the MainActor, and then the `.session.delegateQueue` would essentially be useless, no?

This is what I have so far, but to me, it "smells funny":

```
struct ARSCNSwiftUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let sessionConfiguration: ARConfiguration
    @Binding var isRunning: Bool
    
    let onRendererNeedsNodeForAnchor: (SCNSceneRenderer, ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?
    let onRendererDidUpdateNodeForAnchor: (SCNSceneRenderer, SCNNode, ARAnchor) -> Void
    let onARSessionDidUpdateFrame: (ARSession, ARFrame) -> Void
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARSCNView {
        
        let view = ARSCNView()
        
        guard ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return view }
        
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // TODO: view.session.delegateQueue = coordinator.workerQueue then a view model has a nonisolated method to handle these?
        #if DEBUG
        view.showsStatistics = true
        #endif
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
        if self.isRunning {
            view.session.run(self.sessionConfiguration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        } else {
            view.session.pause()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
        var parent: ARSCNSwiftUIView
        init(_ parent: ARSCNSwiftUIView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
            self.parent.onARSessionDidUpdateFrame(session, frame)
        }
        
        public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
            return self.parent.onRendererNeedsNodeForAnchor(renderer, anchor)
        }
        
        public func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            self.parent.onRendererDidUpdateNodeForAnchor(renderer, node, anchor)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `self` because it's a struct value not a object reference so change to:

```
 func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
```

Also you need to use the new version of the closures, e.g.

```
func updateUIView(_ view: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
    context.coordinator.onARSessionDidUpdateFrame = onARSessionDidUpdateFrame
    // etc.
```

```
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
         var onARSessionDidUpdateFrame: ((ARSession, ARFrame) -> Void)?
    
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
            onARSessionDidUpdateFrame(session, frame)
        }
```

Comment: This is a helpful improvement!  Thank you.  I'm still wondering what to do about the `session.delegateQueue` property, as I'd like to process anything coming out of the ARSessionDelegate off the main thread, and I guess I'm mixing up a few techs at the same time.   My ViewModel was declared to run on MainActor, although it has a member that doesn't need to be isolated to the MainActor.   Complicated problem...

Comment: I should also add that what I have above in my OP works just fine.  It's just handling the concurrency part that now has me confused.